# How can I replicate this table in LateX?

Tags: tables, msword

Can anyone help me in making a table shown below? I created it in MS Word, and I'd like to recreate it in LaTeX, but I'm finding that quite difficult to do...

[image: Table]

Comment: Here you can find an Excel-Add-in, which exports your table as LateX: [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/)

Comment: You may also find this article interesting: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-3/tb90hoeppner.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This should be a starting point. (And I was bored anyway `;-)`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}p{2cm}Xp{2cm}}
    \toprule
    \centering\textbf{Technique Used} &
    \centering\textbf{Premise Considered} &
    \centering\textbf{Attributes} &
    \centering\textbf{Approach} \cr
    \midrule
    Potential Fields \cite{potfield} &
    Location information and range &
    Balanced deployment with the help of repulsive mechanism, when in proximity to obstacles &
    \cr
    %
    Distributed self spreading algorithm (DSSA) \cite{DSSA} &
    Location information &
    A profitable scheme to conserve energy during deployment of a WSN divided into clusters &
    \multirow{-2}{2cm}{Virtual forces} \cr
    Co-Fi \cite{cofi} &
    Location information &
    Ditributed scheme to conserve energy and provide regulated coverage fidelity &
    \cr
    VEC, VOR, Minmax \cite{vec} &
    Location information &
    Identify coverage holes and enabling sensors to move away from dense area &
    \multirow{-2}{2cm}{Computational geometry} \cr
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{A table, which was ported from Excel}
\end{table}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{potfield} Doe, John. \emph{Description of Potential Field Methods}. Journal of Fields \textbf{21}, 100--110, 1990.
\bibitem{DSSA} Nobody, Frank. \emph{Introducing the DSSA Methods}. Methods Rev. \textbf{10}, 62--68, 2001.
\bibitem{cofi} Doe, Jane. \emph{Co-Fi and its Applications}. Rev. Co-Fi. \textbf{17}, 80--89, 2003.
\bibitem{vec} Fawkes, Guy. \emph{VEC, VOR and Minmax -- What's the difference?}. J. Vec. Vor. \textbf{99}, 221000, 1996.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: @JerilK If you like my answer and it was helpful to you, consider upvoting and marking it as [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) by clicking on the checkmark ✓ next to the score.